# Is there a way to manage Microsoft DNS *without* using WMI?

Tags: c#-4.0, network-programming, dns, wmi

We have a need to manage our DNS records (add/update) remotely using C#... I know of and have written/implemented a solution using WMI but the problem is that WMI can be painfully slow.

I have come across the [DNS Provider API](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd278634.aspx) used by the Microsoft Provisioning Framework. Having searched some more though, it seems as if this framework has been retired.

So, does anyone out there know if it's possible to manage a Microsoft DNS without using WMI? As of yet, my only other alternative is to write a TCP server that manipulates the DNS files directly or executes the WMI calls locally on the machine (which seems to operate much faster).

Thanks, J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, doesn't seem like anyone had any answers or suggestions so I had to get a little creative... After a lot of consideration and a very strong desire NOT to write my own TCP server for this purpose I fell upon another, equally acceptable solution: web services.

The biggest problem we've experienced with WMI is only when making calls from a remote network (remote machines on the same LAN seem to operate fine) so really I just needed some framework to use as a proxy for the WMI calls. So I ended up writing a simple web service and things are working great; no having to worry about custom threading on an in-house TCP server or encrypting packets thanks to SSL.

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem!
J